# Quote Form pulls data but does not pass the information once submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

In my code below, I need the Date, Product Name and Product ID to not only get pulled when the quote button is pressed but also passed when the form is submitted. Currently the three do not get sent in the email when we receive it only the other fields appear. We need all of the information to appear. They show up when you press the Get A Quote button and the form shows up, but when the user submits the form the first three do not get passed. If anyone has any idea or can help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
<div id="quoteform">
<form name="eMail" method="post" action="/emailform.asp" class="clear" id="application">
    <div class="full-raw">
        <div class="titlequote">
            -GET A QUOTE-
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="full-raw">
        <div class="smtextinstr">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="full-raw">
        <div class="titlehelp">
        For Help, Please Call</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controllswrapper">

<div class="full-raw reqtext">  
<div class="faq-content faq-content-more">
<div class="faq-contentimportant">
<b>IMPORTANT! Please Read Before Continuing</b>
</div>
<br/>
Get-A-Quote is for quoting one individual item only. If you would like a quote for more         than one item at a time, please click Add to Cart for each individual item. Then when you   are ready to submit your quote request, click "Checkout" in your cart window.
</div>


</div>
 </div>


        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Date:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <div class="dayfield"></div>
            </div>
</div>



<div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Product Name:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <div class="pname"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Product ID:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <div class="pid"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="full-raw reqtext">              
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Quantity:
                <span class="requireditem">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
<input type="text" value="1" maxlength="4" size="3"   id="Quantity" name="Quantity" class="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Full Name:
                <span class="requireditem">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
    <input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName" class="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Title
                <span class="requireditem">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
    <input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" class="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Facility Name
                <span class="requireditem">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
    <input type="text" id="FacilityName" name="FacilityName" class="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Facility Description:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                     <select name="FacilityDesc">
                 <option selected="">Please Select</option>
                 <option value="Commercial Real Estate">Commercial Real Estate</option>
                 <option value="Education">Education</option>
                 <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
                 <option value="Club/Entertainment">Club/Entertainment</option>
                 <option value="Government">Government</option>
                 <option value="GSA">GSA</option>
                 <option value="Food Service">Food Service</option>
                 <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>
                 <option value="Industry">Industry</option>
                 <option value="Reseller">Reseller</option>
                            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Shipping Address:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
    <input type="text" id="ShippingAddress" name="ShippingAddress"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
State / Province:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <select name="StateProvince">
                    <option selected="">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                   <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                    <option value="NL">Newfoundland</option>
                <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
                    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                    <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                    <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Country:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <select name="Country">
                    <option>United States of America</option>
                    <option>Canada</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Zip Code:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <input type="text" name="ZipCode"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Phone:
                <span class="requireditem">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
    <input type="text" name="Phone" class="required phone"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Fax:
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <input type="text" name="Fax" class="phone"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Email:
                <span class="requireditem">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email_From" class="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Taxable?:

            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <select name="Taxable">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Have You Previously Purchased from Us?:
                <span class="requireditem">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
                <select name="PreviouslyPurchased" class="required">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Special Instructions:

            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="40" name="Special Instructions"  ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-raw reqtext">
            <div class="cell-label">
Comments/Questions:

            </div>
            <div class="cell-controls">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="40" name="Comments / Questions" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Remove all Hidden Inputs if No Captcha-->
<input type="hidden" name="email_To" value="placeemailhere"/>
<input type="hidden" name="email_Subject" value="Get A Quote Form Submission"/>
<input type="hidden" name="email_ThankYou" value="Thank you for submitting your request. We will be contacting you within 12 business hours with your requested quote."/>
    <input type="hidden" name="email_Redirect" value=""/>


<div class="verification_code">
                <div>
                    $(Verification_Image)<br/>
<input type="text" name="Verification_Code" id="verification_code"  class="required"/>
</div>
   <p>
    Please enter text exactly as it appears above<span class="asterik">*</span>
                </p>
                </div>

        <div class="btn-sm btn-app btn-sm-prog" name="submit">
            submit application
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript for the Quote Form. If this can help, please let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.vCSS_input_addtocart').after('<div class="btnquotewrapper"><img     src="/v/vspfiles/templates/160/images/btn_getaquote.gif" class="btnquote"/></div>');
$('.v65-productDisplay-row a.colors_text').after('<div class="btnquotewrapper"><img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/160/images/btn_getaquote_small.gif" class="btnquotelist" data- pname="" data-pid=""/></div>');
var i=-1;
$('.btnquotelist').each(function(){
i++;
$(this).attr('data-pname', $($('.colors_productname')[i]).html());
$(this).attr('data-pid', $($('.colors_text b')[i]).html());
});




$('.btnquotelist').bind('click', function(ev){
var node = $(ev.currentTarget);


var hosturl = get_hostname(window.location.href);
var pname = node.attr('data-pname');
var pid = node.attr('data-pid');
 pid = pid.substring(1) 
hosturl  = hosturl  + '/Articles.asp?ID=288&pname='+pname+'&pid='+pid;

$.get( hosturl, function(data) {
var urlparamobj = getQueryParams(hosturl);
var prodid = urlparamobj.pid;
var pname = urlparamobj.pname;

var content = $(data).find('#div_articleid_288').html();
var vday = GetDayToday();



$('.tempholder').html(content);
$('.tempholder').find('.pname').html('<input type="text" id="ProductName" value="'+pname+'"  style="width:300px" disabled/>');
$('.tempholder').find('.pid').html('<input type="text" id="ProductID" value="'+pid+'" disabled/>');
$('.tempholder').find('.dayfield').html('<input type="text" name="dateplaced"     id="dateplaced"value="'+vday+'" disabled/>');



content = '<div class="quoteform">'+$('.tempholder').html()+'</div>';
$('.tempholder').html('');

Shadowbox.open({
        content: content,
        player: "html",
        title: "",
        height: '900',
        width: '800',
        enableKeys: false
      });

});
});





$('.btnquote').bind('click', function(){
var hosturl = get_hostname(window.location.href);
var pname = $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content');
var pid = $('.product_code').text() ? $('.product_code').text() :     $('input[name="ProductCode"]').val();
hosturl  = hosturl  + '/Articles.asp?ID=288&pname='+pname+'&pid='+pid;



$.get( hosturl, function(data) {

var urlparamobj = getQueryParams(hosturl);
var prodid = urlparamobj.pid;
var pname = urlparamobj.pname;
var vday = GetDayToday();

var content = $(data).find('#div_articleid_288').html();
$('.tempholder').html(content);
$('.tempholder').find('.pname').html('<input type="text" id="ProductName"     value="'+pname+'"  style="width:300px" disabled/>');
$('.tempholder').find('.pid').html('<input type="text" id="ProductID" value="'+pid+'"     disabled/>');
$('.tempholder').find('.dayfield').html('<input type="text" name="dateplaced"     id="dateplaced"value="'+vday+'" disabled/>');

content = '<div class="quoteform">'+$('.tempholder').html()+'</div>';
$('.tempholder').html('');


Shadowbox.open({
        content: content,
        player: "html",
        title: "",
        height: '900',
        width: '800',
        enableKeys: false
      });
})
});

$(document).delegate('.required', 'focus', function(ev) {

var node = $(ev.currentTarget);
if (node.val() == node.data('validation')) {
node.val('');
}
if (node.hasClass('reqvalidate')) {
node.removeClass('reqvalidate');
node.val('');
//node.parents('.cf-row').find('.valerror').html('').fadeOut();
}
if (node.val() =='' && node.hasClass('fieldval') == false) {
node.addClass('fieldval');
}
});
$(document).delegate('.required', 'focusout', function(ev) {
var node = $(ev.currentTarget);
if (node.val()=='' && node.data('validation') !=''){
node.val(node.data('validation'));
node.removeClass('fieldval');
}
});
$(document).delegate('.btn-app', 'click', function(ev) {
var node = $(ev.currentTarget);
var reqfields = $('.required');
var errcount = 0;
var email = $('#email').val();
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
for(var i=0; i<reqfields.length; i++ ) {
var item = $(reqfields[i]);
if ((item.val() == '') || (item.val() == item.data('validation'))) {
errcount = errcount + 1;
item.val(item.data('validation'));
item.addClass('reqvalidate');
}
}
if (email != '') {
if (reg.test(email) == false) {
//$('.err-valid-email').html('Invalid Email Address');
//$('.err-valid-email').fadeIn();
errcount = errcount + 1;
$('#email').addClass('reqvalidate');
}
}
if (errcount ==0) {
$('#application').submit();
}
});



$('.phone').bind('click' , function(ev){
var node = $(ev.currentTarget);
node.mask("(999) 999-9999");
});


$(document).delegate('.phone', 'click', function(ev) {
var node = $(ev.currentTarget);
node.mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
});


function get_hostname(url) {
    var m = url.match(/^http:\/\/[^/]+/);
    return m ? m[0] : null;
}
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

    var params = {}, tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }
    return params;
}

function GetDayToday(){
 var mydate=new Date()
        var year=mydate.getYear()
        if (year < 1000)
        year+=1900
        var day=mydate.getDay()
        var month=mydate.getMonth()
        var daym=mydate.getDate()
        if (daym<10)
        daym="0"+daym
        var montharray=new     Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October    ","November","December")
        return montharray[month]+" "+daym+", "+year;


}
```

Comment: What happens when you change your submit div to a button? `<button class="btn-sm btn-app btn-sm-prog" name="submit">submit application</button>`

Comment: It didn't work. Not sure how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Form information is only passed through a submission when:

a) there is an html input and

b) the input has a `name`

The reason the values are not available is because you've just created `<div>` elements for date, product name, and product ID.

You will need to create some kind of inputs, each with a corresponding name.

```
<input type='date' name='date' />
<input type='text' name='productName' />
<input type='text' name='productID' />
```

Once you add the inputs, the values will be submitted.

Comment: Will it still pull the data and not leave the field blank?

Comment: As long as there is text in the inputs, then the data will be retrieved. Otherwise the value will be an empty string; `""`.

Comment: I should have clarified my statement. I meant to say will the fields have data in them when the user brings the form up. At the current moment they do get pulled but are not editable by the user and don't get passed. So will giving them a type 1) make them editable by the user and 2) be blank when user pulls the form up. If 2 is to be the case I do not want that, I would prefer if the customer did not have to fill that out and make it easier for them.

Comment: How are you filling the current divs with information on page load? You could do the same thing with the form inputs, and if need you can also make them editable.

Comment: I think it is through a Javascript file. When you click on the products "Get A Quote" button, the form pops up. The first 3 fields are set and have the information in them already figured out. It has the Date, the Product Name and the Product ID. When I added your input fields into the code it added extra fields off to the side of the already permanent ones and they had nothing in them. So I think it is calling the information from the .js file. I am getting really confused now. I am not the original programmer, they worked on this back in January and now are no longer around.

Comment: ....well, then I can't help you. But I bet if you add the div class name to the inputs, it might add the text to the fields. The depends on how it's being inserted whether it's using .text() or .val()--but it's worth a shot. My advice is to find out where the values are being inserted, but you will need to use text inputs, and not divs. `<input type='date' name='date' class='dayfield' />`

Comment: Tried that too and it did not seem to work. I've included the Javascript up above, I hope this helps.